# Is a bilinear map $\cdot: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with no zero divisors smooth?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

No zero divisors as in if $xy = 0$ then $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you're saying. By no zero divisors, you mean that if I take a bilinear map $B: \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and $B(x,y)=0$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then at least one of $x$ or $y$ is also the zero vector?

Comment: Yes. In other words, I'm trying to prove that if $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a division algebra, its multiplication is smooth, without appealing to the fact that there are only four such $n$ and checking them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Any bi-linear map of finite dimensional vector spaces is smooth. It is easy to see e.g. by the universal property of tensor product (any bi-linear map lifts to a linear map from the tensor product which is smooth), or just right from the definition (derivatives with respect to every coordinate exist). they actually are given by homogeneous polynomials of degree 2.